# How far can a moving object embed itself

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, electrons, particle-accelerators

Let's say we have an electron moving at 10% the speed of light toward a 10 cm thick block of pure carbon. How do we calculate the distance that the electron travels into the carbon?

Even though there is a chance of the electron bouncing off the surface of the carbon, I am only asking the range of distances that the electron could travel before stopping. Is it possible to calculate such a thing? I also believe that relativistic effects are going to come into play?

Comment: For a baseball pitched at 90% of c, see https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these electrons will penetrate, on average, a macroscopic distance into carbon: 40 cm. So many of them would go right through your 10 cm block.

For $v/c=0.1$, we have $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}=1.005$, so the electron's kinetic energy is $K=(\gamma-1)mc^2=(0.005)(511\,\text{KeV})=2.5\,\text{KeV}$. Note that this is considerably less than the kinetic energies of electrons in carbon atoms; for example, since carbon has atom number 6, the fast-moving inner electrons have an energy about 6 times those in hydrogen, or only about $80\,\text{eV}$. The incident electrons are at least 30 times more energetic.

So you are asking for the mean free path of a 2.5 KeV electron in carbon. The electron is scattering off of the electrically charged protons and the electrons in the carbon atoms. But at this incident energy, I think they are mainly scattering off the nuclei. The atomic electrons just "get out of the way". The nuclei are too massive to do that.

When a scattering process occurs, the mean free path is given by $$\ell=\frac{1}{\sigma n}$$ where $\sigma$ is the scattering cross section and $n$ is the number density of the scattering sites (i.e., how many per unit volume).

Carbon has a mass density of $\delta=2.3\times 10^3\,\text{kg}/\text{m}^3$ and a single carbon atom has a mass of $m=2.0\times 10^{-26}\,\text{kg}$ so the number density of carbon nuclei causing the incident electron to scatter is $n=\delta/m=1.1\times 10^{29}/\text{m}^3$.

The cross section of a 2.5 KeV electron on a carbon nucleus (or on a carbon atom) is harder to calculate; it's a quantum electrodynamics calculation. Let's just make a simple order-of-magnitude estimate that the cross section is $\sigma=\pi a_C^2=2.3\times 10^{-29}\,\text{m}^2$ where $a_C=2.7\times 10^{-15}\,\text{m}$ is the radius of a carbon nucleus.

Then the mean free path is $$\ell=\frac{1}{(2.3\times 10^{-29}\,\text{m}^2)(1.1\times 10^{29}/\text{m}^3)}=0.4\,\text{m}.$$

The reason that it penetrates so far is basically that atoms are mostly empty space. Nuclei are very tiny.

Correction: Even though this answer has been accepted, I'm not happy with it. I have used a gross underestimate of the cross section, and therefore gotten too long a mean free path. The scattering is essentially electrostatic, and of course the electric field of the nucleus extends far outside the nucleus itself (but then gets screened by the fields of the electrons, so it doesn't extend far outside the atom). I think the right way to think of the scattering is as (essentially classical!) Rutherford scattering of a Z=1 electron on a Z=6 nucleus. However, I need to remember how to handle the divergence of the Rutherford cross section.

Second try: Rutherford scattering should be a reasonable approximation because the incident electron isn't highly relativistic. The differential cross section for Rutherford scattering is

$$\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=\frac{a_K^2}{\sin^4{\frac{\theta}{2}}}$$

where

$$a_K=\frac{Z_1 Z_2 \alpha\hbar c}{4K}$$

Here $\alpha$ is the fine structure constant, $\hbar$ is the reduced Planck constant, and $c$ is the speed of light.

Using $\hbar c=197\,\text{Mev-fm}$, the numerical value of $a_K$ when $Z_1=1$, $Z_2=6$, and $K=2.5\,\text{KeV}$ is

$$a_K=8.6\times 10^{-13}\,\text{m}.$$

Now we have to integrate the differential cross section over all scattering angles:

$$\sigma=\int d\Omega \frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=2\pi a_K^2\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin{\theta}\,d\theta}{\sin^4{\frac{\theta}{2}}}$$

This integral diverges as $\theta\rightarrow 0$, but physically we cut it off at some small angle $\theta_0$ because the electric field of the nucleus gets screened by the atomic electrons. Doing this gives

$$\sigma=2\pi a_K^2 \int_{\theta_0}^\pi \frac{\sin{\theta}\,d\theta}{\sin^4{\frac{\theta}{2}}}=4\pi a_K^2\left(\frac{1}{\sin^2{\frac{\theta_0}{2}}}-1\right).$$

So, what to use for the cutoff angle $\theta_0$?

In Rutherford scattering, the scattering angle $\theta$ is related to the impact parameter $b_K$ (which is the distance at which the electron would pass by the nucleus if there was no electrostatic attraction) by

$$b_K=2 a_K \cot{\frac{\theta}{2}}$$

Since screening of the nucleus by the atomic electrons means that there should be little scattering when the impact parameter exceeds the radius of the atom (which for a carbon atom is $7.0\times 10^{-11}\,\text{m}$), we can find the cutoff angle from

$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{7.0\times 10^{-11}\,\text{m}}{8.6\times 10^{-13}\,\text{m}}=\cot{\frac{\theta_0}{2}}.$$

This gives $$\theta_0=0.049,$$ from which we then find $$\sigma=1.5\times 10^{-20}\,\text{m}^2$$

and

$$\ell=6.1\times 10^{-10}\,\text{m},$$

a reduction of about nine orders of magnitude from my previous result. (Oops!)

Since the inter-atomic spacing in carbon is about $$d=n^{-1/3}=2.1\times 10^{-10}\,\text{m},$$

I now think the incident electron gets only about 3 atomic layers into the carbon. Basically, at low energy, the scattering cross section is much closer to the cross-section size of the atom (because the electrostatic field of the nucleus matters throughout this region) than to the cross-sectional size of the nucleus.

I'll be interested to see what other people think.

Comment: If you consider a more energetic electron, say with 1 MeV of kinetic energy, $K$ is 400 times greater and $\ell$ is 160,000 times greater, or about a tenth of a millimeter, which is starting to be macroscopic. At 1 GeV it would be a million times longer still, or 100 meters. I don’t know how much all this would change if you tried to do a relativistic analysis.

Comment: What about larger atoms like iron?

Comment: For iron $Z_2=26$, and Google will tell you that the atomic radius is 126 pm. So just put these numbers into the same analysis that I gave. The important thing to realize is that the kinetic energy of the electron is the most important number because it has a huge range. You can have low-energy electrons that don’t penetrate far, or high-energy electrons that do.

Comment: I mean as in using iron ions instead of electron

Comment: Then set $Z_1=26$ for a completely ionized iron nucleus and keep $Z_2=6$ for carbon atoms. The formula takes care of iron’s greater mass through $K$, its kinetic energy. For a given speed, an iron nucleus will have more kinetic energy than an electron. It’s not the mass or the speed of the incident particle that matters, but rather their combination as its kinetic energy.

Comment: Could you please explain why Z = 1 for electron and what Z stands for. I taught myself most of the physics I know, so I don't know what different letters stand for very well.

Comment: $Z$ is a common symbol for atomic number, which is the number of protons in the nucleus, or the charge of the nucleus in units of $e$. I'm using it in a slightly looser way so that it applies to any charged particle, such as an electron. In other words, $q=Ze$. Technically, for an electron $Z$ would be -1, but the formula for Rutherford scattering only involves the square of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$.

Comment: Why does it only apply to the nucleus and not to the surrounding electrons? Also, If it applies to the nucleus, then shouldn't the electrons be attracted instead of deflected as you'd expect with protons?

Comment: I'm ignoring the atomic electrons in carbon. I argued that they have so little mass and kinetic energy that they don't matter. The energetic incoming particle, and the heavy carbon nuclei are what matters. Maybe this is a good approximation and maybe it isn't. A better calculation taking all the 12 electrons in carbon into account would be complicated and isn't the kind of thing one does in 10 minutes for a SE post.

Comment: An incoming electron is attracted to a carbon nucleus, while an incoming nucleus like an iron ion is repelled. But the scattering trajectory of both is a hyperbola. The incoming particle is scattered through some angle $\theta$ in one case and $-\theta$ in the other, depending on "which way" it goes around the carbon nucleus.

Comment: Ok. If you don’t mind me asking, given a magnetic field with strength B and mass m and velocity v, would the Radius of a stable orbit would be mv/qB?

Comment: This has nothing to do with this question. Please post a new question.